# Showing that $\dfrac{\sin \alpha-\sin \beta}{\cos \beta-\cos \alpha}=\cot \theta$ for some $\theta$ between $\alpha$ and $\beta$

Tags: trigonometry

I am stuck on the following problem that says:

> Show that $$\frac{\sin \alpha-\sin \beta}{\cos \beta-\cos \alpha}=\cot \theta$$ where $0 \lt \alpha \lt \theta \lt \beta \lt \frac{\pi}{2}$.

Can someone explain in details? Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: What have you tried? This also seems evidently false, unless some other assumption has been omitted, since cotangent is surely not constant on the open interval $(a, b)$.

Comment: If $\alpha = \pi/10, \theta = \pi/4, \beta = \pi/3$ this seems to be false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply *Cauchy's mean value theorem*:

> If $f$ and $g$ are continuous on the closed interval $[\alpha,\beta]$, differentiable on its interior $(\alpha,\beta)$, there exists $\theta \in  (\alpha,\beta)$ such that
>   $$\frac{f(\alpha)-f(\beta)}{g(\alpha)-g(\beta)}=\frac{f'(\theta)}{g'(\theta)}.$$

Comment: That's what I wanted.

Comment: Very nice answer (+1).

Answer (score 4):

Notice that:

$$\sin(\alpha) - \sin(\beta) = 2\sin\left(\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\right)$$

$$\cos(\beta) - \cos(\alpha) = 2\sin\left(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}\right)$$

Their ratio is:

$$\cot(\theta) = \displaystyle\frac{\cos\left(\displaystyle\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\right)}{\sin\left(\displaystyle\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\right)},$$

where $\theta = \displaystyle\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}.$

Comment: Thanks a lot ..Got it..

Comment: Very cute! (+1)